# python simple json error ? or API error?

Tags: python

I have these code here http://pastebin.com/YHpZQ9Z9

After a few interval randomly, the error pops out and I cannot debug on what is causing the problem, can any professional help me ?

I encounter these error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
run()    

weather_Connection(intervalone)

response = get_response(conn, url)

return json.loads(data)

return _default_decoder.decode(s)

obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

return _scan_once(string, idx)

raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is probably returning an invalid json,
it returns 502 status intermitttently

"https://api.forecast.io/forecast/59ff8cb7661d231f2967c2663c0a3bdc/1.37871,103.848808"

Comment: Any idea how can i fix this ? The website is sometimes unstable and is returning invalid key, but after a few refreshes it work. How can I counter measure this ?

Comment: You can use memcached to store valid responses for few minutes, the forecasts do not change in that time, and that would make your app faster as ewll.

Comment: Instead of httplib I prefer to use requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I don't get it when <------- # HOST NOT USED HERE ? How to put host there?

Comment: @Helpme, that code was correct, ignore my comment. The only error is 502 being returned from the api, you have to check the status and proceed accordingly.